Why write the return type of a type guard as `this is (…) & this` in TypeScript?
I'm reading the Classes section of the handbook, but there is a difference that makes me confused.
In the following examples:

In Example 1, they first explicitly wrote the return type this is Networked & this. I can understand this part.

Then, in Example 2, they only did this is { value: T }, but the type of box in the if-block is Box<string> & { value: string; }.


I don't know why the second case works. Based on the first example, I expect that it should be this is { value: T } & this instead. Does it mean I can always omit the explicit & this?

Example 1
class FileSystemObject {
  isFile(): this is FileRep {
    return this instanceof FileRep;
  }
  isDirectory(): this is Directory {
    return this instanceof Directory;
  }
  isNetworked(): this is Networked & this { // the return type here.
    return this.networked;
  }
  constructor(public path: string, private networked: boolean) {}
}
 
class FileRep extends FileSystemObject {
  constructor(path: string, public content: string) {
    super(path, false);
  }
}
 
class Directory extends FileSystemObject {
  children: FileSystemObject[];
}
 
interface Networked { // this interface that matters.
  host: string;
}
 
const fso: FileSystemObject = new FileRep("foo/bar.txt", "foo");
 
if (fso.isFile()) {
  fso.content;
} else if (fso.isDirectory()) {
  fso.children;
} else if (fso.isNetworked()) {
  fso.host; // const fso: Networked & FileSystemObject
}


Example 2
class Box<T> {
  value?: T;
 
  hasValue(): this is { value: T } { // here, there is no `& this`.
    return this.value !== undefined;
  }
}
 
const box = new Box<string>();
box.value = "Gameboy";
 
if (box.hasValue()) {
  box.value; // notice the type of box here.
}



I am confused in the opposite direction. Writing this is this looks redundant.

It definitely looks like this is type predicates as implemented in ms/TS#5906 do not actually care if the guarded type is a narrowing of the input type, unlike normal type predicates which will give you a TS2677 error if you try that as shown here. My guess is that classes are intentionally looser so that subclasses don't accidentally invalidate the type predicate. But I don't see an existing doc/issue anywhere saying it for sure. If you're very interested you might open a GitHub issue for it.

(see prev comment) If you do open an issue and get an official answer there then you could come back here and post it with a link. Otherwise I just don't know if there's a great way to get an objective answer here to why it works. The fact that it works can be determine experimentally or by stepping through the compiler, but I don't know how useful that is for people, especially if there's no doc saying that it works.

Tried it just in case: yes, you can omit this. The type guard is always performed on the this instance, the narrowed version is always some variant of this, typescript is smart enough to do that.
Works the same as Extract
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union
